# Flutter: Safari cannot open the page because the address in invalid

Tags: ios, flutter, url, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to do something super simple just launch the android or apple play store from my app so a user can go rate the app from my settings but I get this error when testing in my iOS simulator:

> Safari cannot open the page because the address in invalid

```
onTap: () {
                if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
                  final url = Uri.parse(
                    Platform.isAndroid
                        ? "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dontforgetthespoon.dont_forget_the_spoon"
                        : "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/dont-forget-the-spoon/id6444052519?platform=iphone",
                  );
                  launchUrl(
                    url,
                    mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
                  );
                }
              }
```

I feel like this should be super simple. Any ideas on what may be going wrong for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easyiest way is to use [launch_review](https://pub.dev/packages/launch_review) flutter package.

```
LaunchReview.launch(androidAppId: "com.example.app",
                    iOSAppId: "511431312");
```

Comment: This package is discontinued.